The method in the controller won't receive the from the view page
The problem is that the method won't receive the id like the title says. I have tried to ckeck and make sure this is the problem by writing console.writeLine(orderId); and it always returns 0 no matter the object.
I had a similar problem earlier and I just had to add a IActionResult method to that one and so I added one for this as well but that wasn't enough. I have a hidden input field in the form which acts like a button and I have made sure not to miss the asp-action to link it to the method. Another reason why I know that the method is connecting but the id is empty is because the method is written in a way that if the id's are null then they should just go to the top of the index page which is exactly what it does. The point of the method is to be able to change the status.
Here is the methods in the controller, Orders is the name of the models class
public IActionResult Index(int orderId, OrderStatus nyStatus)
{
    var andraInfo = new Orders();
    andraInfo.Id = orderId;
    andraInfo.Status = nyStatus;
    return View(andraInfo);
}

//-----------------------------------

public IActionResult AndraStatus(int orderId, OrderStatus nyStatus)
{

    Console.WriteLine(orderId);
    
    var order = _context.Orders.Find(orderId);

    //var order = _context.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == orderId);

    // Kontrollera om ordern finns
    if (order != null)
    {
        // Uppdatera statusen på ordern
        order.Status = nyStatus;

        // Spara ändringarna i databasen
        _context.Update(order);
        _context.SaveChanges();

    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

The view index page
@foreach (var hat in Model)
{
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Namn på hatten: @hat.Title</h5>
            @foreach (var order in hat.HatsOrders)
            {
                <div class="card mb-3 ">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            <form asp-controller="Order" asp-action="AndraStatus" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nyStatus">Välj ny status:</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="nyStatus" name="nyStatus">
                                        @foreach (var status in Enum.GetValues(typeof(OrderStatus)))
                                        {
                                            <option value="@status">@status</option>
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                @* <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="@order.Id" />
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Uppdatera status</button> *@
                                <form method="post" >
                                    <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="@order.Id">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  value="Uppdatera status" >

                                </form>
                            </form>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <p class="card-text">Status: @order.Orders.Status</p>
                        }
                        @if (order.Orders.UserId is null)
                        {
                            <p>Det finns ingen som är ansvarig för hatten</p>

                            @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                            {
                                <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="LaggTillAnsvarig" asp-route-id="@order.Orders.UserId">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Markera mig som ansvarig</button>
                                </form>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <p class="card-text">Ansvarig: @order.Orders.Users.UserName</p>
                        }
                        <hr />
                        <p class="card-text">Kund</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Förnamn: @order.Orders.Customers?.Firstname</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Efternamn: @order.Orders.Customers?.Lastname</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}

thanks btw

I'm really confused why you post some of your codes and just only post some of your codes, it's really hard for me to figure out what is HatsOrders, OrderStatus, Orders, Order. By the way, why we require to put a form inside a form?

I recommend you follow the MVC tutorial to read more about form submit, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-8.0

In the meantime, you define the form submit method as post. Do you have [HttpPost] before your AndraStatus method?

It would be better to use a proper view model when posting data to the server. I would start by restructuring the code to use an approach similar to the one below:
 public class OrderViewModel
 {
     public int orderId { get; set; }
     public OrderStatus nyStatus { get; set; }
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult AndraStatus(OrderViewModel viewModel)
 {
    var order = _context.Orders.Find(viewModel.orderId);
 }

This will make sure that your form controls are bound to the view model.
